# How to pass two different parameters through the same form in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I have a route defined above

```
app.post('/calendar/:move', calendar.verifyMoveParam, calendar.move);
```

The middleware verifyMoveParam is there to verify if the param passed through url is next or prev, code above:

```
// POST /calendar/:move
  controller.verifyMoveParam = function(req, res, next) {

    if(req.params.move.search(/^(next|prev)$/) === -1) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    } else {
      req.move = req.params.dir;
      next();
    }

  };
```

And then moves to the move middleware which should have all the logic, code above:

```
// POST /calendar/:move
  controller.move = function(req, res) {

    if(req.move == 'next') {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }

    res.render('calendar', {});

  };
```

But i don't know how to pass two different parameters through my form template:

```
<form method='post' action='/calendar'>
  <li class="prev"><button type="submit" name="prev">&#010094;</button></li>
  <li class="next"><button type='submit' name='next'>&#010095;</button></li>
</form>
```

To run correctly the form should be able to pass two parameters 'prev' when the user clicks on the first button and 'next' when click on second button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a couple issues with your code.  First, your current route is looking for the move parameter, which is going to be in the URL path structure.  That's not something the buttons will affect without additional clientside trickery, which isn't great.

Further, even if you did do that your middleware is not consistent; in one place you're looking for `req.params.move` and in another you're looking at `req.params.dir`.

Given that you're using a POST action, the most reasonable place to put the direction is going to be in the body of the POST rather than in the params or querystring.  So as @DarinDimitrov said, your form should change to:

```
<form method="post" action="/calendar">
    <li class="prev">
        <input type="submit" name="move" value="prev">&#010094;</input>
    </li>
    <li class="next">
        <input type="submit" name="move" value="next">&#010095;</input>
    </li>
</form>
```

But your routing and middleware will also need to change to handle that.

```
// route doesn't need the :move param anymore
app.post('/calendar', calendar.verifyMoveParam, calendar.move);

// POST /calendar
  controller.verifyMoveParam = function(req, res, next) {

    if(req.body.move.search(/^(next|prev)$/) === -1) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    } else {
      req.move = req.body.move;
      next();
    }

  };
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer, it was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving your submit buttons the same name but a different value:

```
<form method="post" action="/calendar">
    <li class="prev">
        <input type="submit" name="move" value="prev">&#010094;</input>
    </li>
    <li class="next">
        <input type="submit" name="move" value="next">&#010095;</input>
    </li>
</form>
```

Now you have got 2 submit buttons with the same `name="move"` and depending on which one is clicked your server side application will receive the corresponding value of the `move` parameter (`prev` or `next`) which you can test against:

```
if (req.move == 'next') {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DarinDimitrov